# how to retrieve form values and labels from react hook form and antd Select

Tags: antd, react-hook-form

I am using antd Select and react hook form via 'Controller'. I am populating the Select options from a fetched data with structure;

{
{
"id": "232342",
"term": "hello"
}
{
"id": "232342",
"term": "hello"
}
}

the Select component properly displays the term for selection. However, i want to retrieve both the 'id'and 'term' of the selected and use it to populate another json object.

getValues(" ") retrieves the 'id' only. How do i retrieve and access both the 'id' and 'term'.

Here is a portion of code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import { Select } from 'antd'



const { Option } = Select

export default function PatientRegistrationForm({ options }) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, getValues, control, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
      defaultValues: {
         customer: "",
      }
  })

    const children = []
    for (const {id, pt: {term}} of options){
        children.push(<Option key={id}>{term}</Option>)
    }



    // Define the retrieved values from the form
        const retrievedID = getValues("customer")
 
        // Use the retreived values to populate this object
        const customer = {
            customerId = retrievedID
            customerName = "nothing happens here"
            },


  return (
      <div className="">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="">
    
            <section>
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name="customer"
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <Select {...field} defaultValue=""
                        bordered={true}
                        filterOption={true}
                        className="form-control"
                       
                    >
                        { children }
                    </Select>
                )} 
            />
            </section>
           </form>
      </div>
    
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve the option manually using something like:

```js
const retrievedID = getValues("customer")
const retrievedOption = options.find(option => option.id === retrievedID)

const customer = {
  customerId: retrievedID,
  customerName: retrievedOption.term
}
```

Comment: That is awesome @sgarcia.dev. Thank you. I am not familiar with this implementation. Tried looking it up to gain more knowledge but found little to that regard. Any pointer  will be appreciated. Thanks once again.

Comment: It's not an implementation directly documented or supported by React-Hook-Form or React-Select because it's something that neither likes. React-Hook-Form binds to raw primitive values (such as ID's), whereas React-Select binds to the more complex option object type. So if you wish to communicate the two, you need to write a manual translation layer such as this one. @user13171920

Answer (score 0):

thank you #sgarcia.dev for your answer. I know its been a while but i want to put it out here incase it helps someone else. It turns out it had little to do with react hook form. Ant design select component has a prop 'labelInValue' which returns an object containing both the label and value.